# Plotting histogram on python with dictionary

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I want to plot the following dictionary on python using matplotlib.pyplot as a histogram.
How can I code it up?

```
{'G': 198, 'T': 383, 'C': 260, 'A': 317}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The histogram would be needed if you *did not* know the frequency of each item. That is, if you had data of the form

```
G G T G C A A T G
```

Since you already know the frequencies, it is just a simple bar plot

```
{'G': 198, 'T': 383, 'C': 260, 'A': 317}
labels, values = zip(*data.items())
plt.bar(labels, values)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use:

```
plt.bar(data.keys(), data.values())
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With pandas:

```
d = {'G': 198, 'T': 383, 'C': 260, 'A': 317}
df = pd.DataFrame({x:[y] for x,y in d.iteritems()}).T
df.plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

[image]